# sendKeys - Send special characters

Tags: android

```
addressBar = (AutoCompleteTextView) mActivity.findViewById(package.R.id.addressBar);
TouchUtils.tapView(this, addressBar);

sendKeys("1");  //Works
sendKeys("G M A I L");  // Works - Result would be "gmail"
sendKeys("G M A I L . C O M");  // Doesn't work
sendKeys("{.}");  // Doesn't work
sendKeys("gmail")  // Doesn't work

sendKeys("G M A I L {.} C O M")  //Doesn't work
```

I am writing android test scripts using "InstrumentationTestCase2". I actually want to sendkeys - "gmail.com" but, unable to send special character "."(Dot)

Comment: Have you tried 
`sendKeys(56)` ?

Comment: Superb man. That worked straight forward.

Comment: If you don't mind I have posted the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `'.'` (period or dot) you can try the `int` equivalent values of it.

Like,

```
sendKeys(56);
```

**From Android-Docs**

```
public static final int KEYCODE_PERIOD

Key code constant: '.' key.
Constant Value: 56 (0x00000038)
```

Answer (score 2):

"The sequence of keys is a string containing the key names as specified in KeyEvent, without the KEYCODE_ prefix." (sendKeys documentation)

So you can use NUMPAD_DOT in the sendKeys string.

e.g.

```
sendKeys("G M A I L NUMPAD_DOT C O M");
```

For Further information see : 
  (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/InstrumentationTestCase.html#sendKeys(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 1):

```
sendKeys(56); // for special character "." (Dot)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following:

```
getInstrumentation().sendStringSync("Do.You@Love.IT???");
```

works like magic and makes life a lot simpler!